# Split mysql row into 2 rows based on 2 column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an output view of timecard data so it can be exported to a payroll system.
Currently, the data structure is like this.

```
|Emp_ID|Date|Job|CostCode|Reg_Hrs|OT_Hrs|
Data
|BR0000|date|012|01234567|0000008|000002|
```

The import process requires Regular hours and OT hours to be on separate lines So my output would need to be something like below:

```
|Emp_ID|T_Date|Job_Code|Cost_Code|Reg_Hrs|OT_Hrs|
Data
|BR0000|..date|00000012|001234567|0000008|000000|
|BR0000|..date|00000012|001234567|0000000|000002|
```

I have tried some variations of UNION ALL statements and gotten close but not quite what I need since the second select does not create correct values or column layout.

```
SELECT `Emp_ID` AS `Emp_ID`,
    `T_Date` AS `T_Date`,
    SUBSTRING(CONCAT(`Job_Num`,`Job_let`),1,7) AS `Job_Code`,
    CONCAT(`Job_Code`, IFNULL(`Equip_Code`,'0000')) AS `Cost_Code,
    `Reg_Hrs` as `Reg_Hrs`,
    `OT_Hrs` as `OT_Hrs`
     FROM `timecard_payroll`
     WHERE `Reg_Hrs` <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT `Emp_ID` AS `Emp_ID`,
       `T_Date` AS `T_Date`,
        SUBSTRING(CONCAT(`Job_Num`,`Job_let`),1,7) AS `Job_Code`,
        CONCAT(`Job_Code`, IFNULL(`Equip_Code`,'0000')) AS `Cost_Code,
        `Reg_Hrs` as `none`,  -- have tried different variations of these last 3 lines
        `OT_Hrs` as `OT_Hrs` FROM `timecard_payroll`
        WHERE `OT_Hrs` <> 0
ORDER BY `Emp_ID`, `T_Date`
```

I may have to write a PHP script to write to a temp table just for the export.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Your sample data and query text does not match. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and show desired output for this data **precisely**.

Answer (score 0):

Formally:

```
SELECT {other columns}, Reg_Hrs * x.x Reg_Hrs, OT_Hrs * (1 - x.x) OT_Hrs
FROM source table
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 x 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 ) x
```